# data.table: Error during wrapup: Internal error: NA exist in 'rows' passed to C assign

Tags: r, data.table

Well, this worked fine for me yesterday in a function I have.  Today I am having the following problem with this data.table.  I cant figure out what I did wrong or changed to get this behavior:

```
dtable
   TIF VENUE duration TYPE1 TYPE2 TYPE3 TYPE4 index order_type
1: DAY    NA  1.3e+07    NA   M:0    NA    NA     2         NA
2: DAY    NA  2.0e+06    NA   M:0    NA    NA     4         NA
3: DAY    NA  8.9e+07    NA   M:0    NA    NA     6         NA
4: IOC    NA  0.0e+00    NA    NA    NA    NA     1         NA
5: IOC    NA  0.0e+00    NA    NA    NA    NA     3         NA
6: IOC    NA  0.0e+00    NA    NA    NA    NA     5         NA

Classes:
        TIF       VENUE    duration       TYPE1       TYPE2       TYPE3       TYPE4    index    order_type
   "factor"    "factor"   "numeric"    "factor"    "factor"    "factor"    "factor"   "integer" "character"





cn = "TYPE2"
pattern = "M:?\\n*\\.?\\n*"
tif = "DAY"
> type
[1] mid-peg
Levels: ERROR? GTC? far-peg far-peg ping limit limit ping mid-peg mid-peg ping near-peg near-peg ping

index = grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])
index
> [1] 1 2 3
```

This fails:

```
dtable[tif][index][,"order_type"] = type              
**Error during wrapup: Internal error: NA exist in 'rows' passed to C assign**
```

This works:

```
dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,"order_type"] = type
> dtable
   TIF VENUE duration TYPE1 TYPE2 TYPE3 TYPE4 index order_type
1: DAY    NA  1.3e+07    NA   M:0    NA    NA     2    mid-peg
2: DAY    NA  2.0e+06    NA   M:0    NA    NA     4    mid-peg
3: DAY    NA  8.9e+07    NA   M:0    NA    NA     6    mid-peg
4: IOC    NA  0.0e+00    NA    NA    NA    NA     1         NA
5: IOC    NA  0.0e+00    NA    NA    NA    NA     3         NA
6: IOC    NA  0.0e+00    NA    NA    NA    NA     5         NA
```

What am I screwing up?

I thought my R session was corrupt so I brought up a new one and it failed as well.

Thank you for your time.

(Sorry folks, first time using this site so I shouldn't have put the following in the comments section)
For the suggestion to use ....[,order_type :- type ]

Here it is: same dtable as above. I left the exmaple in memory with the same parms above.

```
>dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,order_type] 
[1] NA NA NA 

>dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,order_type := type ] 
>dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,order_type] 
[1] NA NA NA 

> type [1] mid-peg. 
[1] mid-peg
Levels: ERROR? GTC? far-peg far-peg ping limit limit ping mid-peg mid-peg ping near-peg near-peg ping
```

Now doing this after, it works:

```
> dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,"order_type"] = type
> dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,order_type] 
[1] "mid-peg" "mid-peg" "mid-peg"
```

I apologize if this looks odd.  When I first started this whole thing, I did originally try:

```
>index = grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])
>dtable[tif][index][,order_type := type ]
```

This didnt work.  I did seem (or thought) I had the following working 2 nights ago:

```
>dtable[tif][index][,"order_type"] = type
```

but now I get the error:
 Internal error: NA exist in 'rows' passed to C assign

After mucking with this for a while, I was surprised that replacing [index] with 
[grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])] worked as it should be the same thing.  So that left me scratching my head back to the original problem way above.

I just started using data.table about a month ago.  It was great advantages and a major boost for me but there are a few odd quirks I have come across, like this one.  So I finally thought I should post this out there to see what I am doing wrong or if I am using data.table in a way not intended.

Totally forgot to mention, I am using R3.0
Thank you all.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but I think you want this at the end of your expression: `.....[, order_type := type]`

Comment: Yes, that is was I did originally and it did nothing. So that is why I did it the final way I showed it. FYI, I did have: dtable[tif][index, order_type := type] No dice. Tried different combinations. Thank you for your response.  By did nothing, I meand that the order_type column did not change and was left with all NA's from initialization.

Comment: try isolating a reproducible example

Comment: Here it is:  same dtable as above.  I left the exmaple in memory with the same parms above.  
>dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,order_type] 
[1] NA NA NA        
dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,order_type := type ]                    
dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,order_type] 
[1] NA NA NA               
> type
[1] mid-peg.

Comment: So that is why I could not use the := operator.  This worked:  
dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,"order_type"] = type
> dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,order_type] 
[1] "mid-peg" "mid-peg" "mid-peg"

As for the original question above, I cant understand why my above works when I replace [index] with [grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])]    when index = grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])

Comment: Sorry if I seem confusing.  I have been getting used to data.table the past month and it works great but some quirks like this catch me.  I wasted some time before I saw that dtable[tif][grep(pattern, dtable[tif][, get(cn)])][,"order_type"] = type works but don't understand why using dtable[tif][index][,"order_type"] does not.

Comment: Edit your question to include these examples. It is too difficult to follow in the comments

Comment: Sorry, please see the updated question.  Thank you for checking.

Comment: SOLVED:  friend of mine spotted this:   dt[tif][index][,"order_type"]="mid-peg"  will work, if there is no column named "index" in the data table dt.  Otherwise it evaluates "index" as a column value and gets c(2,4,6) as the row indices, which won't work since dtf[tif]  has only 3 rows.  i.e., rename your "index" column to "INDEX".
What a dope I am.  This explains why this function worked one night and failed the next.  My object the next day had a column names "index" in it which wasnt there the day before.  Thank  you.

Answer (score 1):

```
dtable[tif][index][,"order_type"] = type
```

will work if there is no column named "index" in the dtable.  Otherwise "index" is evaluated as column values, which in this case are (2,4,6), which won't refer to valid row numbers in dtable[tif].